# how can I drop user from "system.users" using mongodb and PHP?

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel-5, mongodb-query, php-mongodb

I need a small help.

I can not delete **"System.User"** user from MongoDB database.

```
/*Remove Tenent DB*/
function RemoveTenentDB($mydb){
   error_reporting(0);
   $connection_string = Config::get('database.creator-tenant-uri');
   $m = new MongoClient($connection_string); //create interface to mongo
   $command = array
   (
       "dropUser" => $mydb
   );
   $db = $m->selectDB( $mydb );
   $db->command( $command );
   #drop databse
   $db = $m->dropDB( $mydb );
   return true;
}
```

Below code delete just database and particular database user only not **"System.User"**

```
$command = array
   (
       "dropUser" => $mydb
   );
   $db = $m->selectDB( $mydb );
   $db->command( $command );
   $db = $m->dropDB( $mydb );
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The following db.dropUser() operation drops the reportUser1 user on the products database.

```
use products
db.dropUser("reportUser1", {w: "majority", wtimeout: 5000})
```

reference : [db.dropUser](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.dropUser/)

Try following code for php

```
$users = $conn->$db_name->selectCollection('system.users')->delete();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but in PHP how can I drop the user ("system.users").
"db.dropUser" yes this function works only current db users only not "system.users" collection.

Answer (score -2):

If I understand it right, you are looking for deleting one collection in mongodb database using PHP. 
If that is the case then, you can use the below method to drop a collection from mongodb.

$collection = $mongo->my_db->System.User;
$response = $collection->drop();

You can follow the below link to get more details about the same - 
https://www.php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.drop.php

Comment: Never do this because of "System.User" is a collection of all DB users.